# sharepoint 2013 form based authentication

Tags: forms-authentication

My project is in SharePoint 2013 I have a site collection  which has two sub sites other than the root site  , suppose the name of the sub sites are x and y ,  I have to implement fba  in this project , 
I have the following scenario
If a user who have access  read access on subsite x logs in  to the root site he is redirected to the site x home page
And same goes for the user who has the read access for subsite y  ,
How can I achieve this , is it possible through out of the box functionality , or do I have to develop something through code (if yes please tell me about it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a webpart to redirect users to different pages,

Here's a freeware webpart available for SharePoint 2010 but I am pretty sure it will work with SP 2013 too.

[SharePoint 2010 User Redirect](http://userredirect.codeplex.com/)

If you want to do it yourself then follow this article,

[Redirection options in SharePoint and then follow steps under "Redirect from Deep URL"](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=48)

Here's a better version of webpart but not sure if it's free, however you can use it figure out what you need to develop your webpart.

[Sneak Peek: User Redirect Web Part for SharePoint 2013](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/03/07/sharepoint-2013-sneak-peek-user-redirect-web-part.aspx)

If you create your own UserControl then on page_load check `userid` and then redirect them using `SPUtility.Redirect`.